# problems with embedding select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to embed a select statement in the from clause but I am getting an error message. I couldn't able to understand what is the problem. Can anyone help me with this? I am using a Postgres database.

```
select
r.recipetitle,
r.preparation,
rcfiltered.classname
from
(
    select
        recipeclassid,
        recipeclassdescription as classname
    from
        recipe_classes as rc
    where
        rc.classname = 'Main course'
        or rc.classname = 'Dessert'
) as rcfiltered
inner join recipes as r on rcfiltered.recipeclassid = r.recipeclassid;
```

The Error Message is - column rc.classname does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing this: `recipeclassdescription as classname`, you need to refer to the column as `recipeclassdescription` in the `WHERE clause`.

`classname` will be available to `WHERE` clauses **outside** of the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have renamed the column.  However, you can drastically simplify your query:

```
select r.recipetitle, r.preparation,
       rc.recipeclassdescription as classname
from recipe_classes rc join
     recipes r
     on rc.recipeclassid = r.recipeclassid
where rc.recipeclassdescription in ('Main course', 'Dessert');
```

Notes:

- No subquery is necessary.
- You should use `IN` rather than repeated `OR` comparisons when comparing a single column.
- The column alias is not recognized in the `WHERE` clause, so you have to use the original column name.